# How to fetch data from Backbone collection to Template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

i am just writing a simple backbone program. But i am not getting how to fetch data from backbone collection to backbone template. Complete code is written below:

```
        <!doctype html>
        <html>
           <head>
              <title>Backbone tutorial</title>
           </head>
           <body>
              <div class="user">user</div>
              <div class="page"></div>

              <script type="text/template" id="user-list-template">
```

I am not able to get data on daya.key

```
                <h1> <%= data.key %> </h1>

              </script>

              <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
              <script type="text/javascript" src="underscore.js"></script>
              <script type="text/javascript" src="backbone.js"></script>
              <script>
```

This is my Collection code

```
                  var Album = Backbone.Collection.extend({

                    url : "/data.json"
                  });
```

This is my view code

```
                 var UserList= Backbone.View.extend({
                    el:'.page',
                    template:_.template($('#user-list-template').html()),
                    render : function(){
                        var that=this;
                        var album= new Album();
                        album.fetch({
                            success:function(album){

                                var _data = {data : album.models} ;

                                $(that.el).html(that.template(_data));
                            }
                        })


                    }

                 });
```

This is my Router code

```
                 var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
                    routes: {
                        "":                 "home"   // #help
                    }


                 });



                 var userList= new UserList();
                 var router = new Router();

                 router.on('route:home', function(){
                    userList.render();
                 });

                 Backbone.history.start();
              </script>
           </body>
        </html>
```

and here is the data.json file

```
{ "key" : "value to print on template "}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two modifications i would suggest

1.First check the data feild in your template. Since you are fetching data from the collection it will be array of models.

`<h1> <%= data[0].key %> </h1>`

or you can use a for loop iterating over the collections

2.The data.json file should look like this

```
[{"key" : "value"}]
```

Comment: Hi nitansh, i have done as per your suggestion, i have debugged and found that its not working with <h1> <%= data[0].key %> </h1>, but its working with <h1> <%= data[0].attributes.key %> </h1>, which should not be case. Will you please provide more help.

Comment: ufff sorry for the template. you have to use `data[0].get('key')`.

Answer (score 0):

Server needs to return a JSON array of model object for collection.fetch() request. So the data.json should look like this:

```
[{"key":"value to print on template"},{"key":"another value"}]
```

And try this collection view render implementation:

**Model:**

```
var User = new Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

**Collection:**

```
var Album = new Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: User,
  url: "/data.json"
});
//create collection instance
var album = new Album();
```

**View:**

```
var UserList= Backbone.View.extend({
    el:'.page',
    template:_.template($('#user-list-template').html()),
    initialize: function(){
      //register a collection data add event handler
      this.listenTo(album,"add",this.addUser);
      //register a collection data remove event handler
      this.listenTo(album,"remove",this.removeUser);
      album.fetch();
    },
    render : function(){

    },
    addUser: function(user){  //apply model data to view template and append to view element
      this.$el.append(this.template(user.toJSON()));
    },
    removeUser: function(user){
      //view state update implementation when data have been removed from collection
    }
 });
```

**Template:**

```
<script type="text/template" id="user-list-template">
  <h1><%= key %></h1>
</script>
```

div.user view will add/remove user-list view dynamically according to collection data manipulation.

Hope this helpful.

Comment: I have gone through the code that you have suggested. But i could not understand "user" that you have passed to the following function:

      addUser: function(user){ 
      this.$el.append(this.template(user.toJSON()));
      },

Please explain how and where should i define user

Comment: Album collection is an ordered set of user model. When a new model is added to collection, it will trigger a "add" event and pass the added model to event handler. Then you can update the view with this model.